mpandroidchart values display on top of the bar dynamically when the bar got too small
I have and android application that use the Mpandroidchart library and I'm struggling with one problem with my values on my Horizontal bar charts
Horizontal Bar
as you can see the value is displayed inside the bar even when the bar is too small, I have tried the setDrawValueAboveBar(boolean enabled) but it also put my values with the large bar to shown on top and get cut on the right side instead. Can anyone help me with this ? I have search anywhere and read the documentation thoroughly and I'm still can't find the solution
solution for my problem, or another example using a different library but close to mpandroidcharts
